# Index serial numbers with text prefix

Tags: excel, serialization

I have a database with that has parts that belong to one of five serial pools. The pools begin with "BPO","BUW","BPI",BPO","BPT". Based on what pool it falls in, a serial number column would add those three letters to a number that advances every time those letters are used. They are not entered in any order. The current database has 46 entries and the code I have works those entered. But when new entries are added it does not index correctly.

```
    =H2&"-" &TEXT(COUNTIF($H$2:$H2,H2),"0000")
```

This is what it gives me and then what adding more entries does:

[image: formula applied to existing]

[image: trying to add new entries]

```
    =H48&"-" &TEXT(COUNTIF($H$2:$H51,H48),"0000")
```

The table originally had 46 entries, any entries beyond that uses the the last entry as a reference. What can I do to help fix this?

Comment: What does it show beyond 46 entries ? Also the second formula is wrong. It should be like If the cell formula is in Row 51  `=H51&"-" &TEXT(COUNTIF($H$2:$H51,H51),"0000")` or  If the cell formula is in Row 48 `=H48&"-" &TEXT(COUNTIF($H$2:$H48,H48),"0000")`